# First route errors in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-router, ember-model

I would like to handle errors that happen in the first route within ember and if the error action is called redirect to another route.

How would i determine if this is a first route upon error being invoked and if it is a first route, re-route to route say index. BUT if it is not first route just return true and let the error bubble up.

Getting this error whenever i retry the transition object

> Uncaught Error: Can't trigger action 'error' because your app hasn't
>   finished transitioning into its first route. To trigger an action on
>   destination routes during a transition, you can call `.send()` on the
>   `Transition` object passed to the `model/beforeModel/afterModel`
>   hooks.

Here is my setup :

```
ember.js:15373 DEBUG: Ember       : 1.8.1
ember.js:15373 DEBUG: Handlebars  : 1.3.0
ember.js:15373 DEBUG: jQuery      : 1.11.3
ember.js:15373 DEBUG: Ember Model : 0.0.14
```

This would be my parent route that all other routes inherit from

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
//This can sometimes return a 500 and i want to re-route incase of error.
model: function(params) {
    return CopyTree.fetchById({
      treeType: params['treeType'],
      id: params['id']
    });
  },
 actions: {
  error: function(error, transition) {
   //FAKE CODE NOT SURE HOW TO TELL I AM IN THE FIRST ROUTE
   if(this.firstRoute){
     this.transitionTo('index');
   } else{
     return true;
    }
   }
 }
});
```

Comment: When i call fetchById on a model i am getting a 500 response from the server (not all the times but sometimes).  I would like to have a catch all to safeguard my code so it doesnt get stuck in transition into its first route

Comment: Are you by any chance using symfony in dev environment?

Comment: Nope, it has nothing to do with the backend logic. That is working how it should based on certain conditions. I just want to handle my ember logic correctly

Comment: what do you mean with firstRoute ?